# Yii2 : How to write Mysql query to select records from two tables using left join

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables which i want to join... i.e. camps & cities.
I have write the query in PHP for this... but I want same query in Yii2 format... Please tell me how can i write this query in yii2...??

**Here is my query :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT camps.city_id, camps.state_id, cities.city_name 
    from camps 
    LEFT JOIN cities
    ON cities.state_id = camps.state_id
    WHERE camps.state_id = 5
    AND camps.status = '1'
    ORDER BY cities.city_name ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use yii\db\Query;

$query  = new Query(); 
$query->select
                       (['camps.city_id AS City, camps.state_id AS State, cities.city_name AS Name'
                       ]) 
                      ->from('camps')
                      ->join('LEFT JOIN',' cities','cities.state_id = camps.state_id')
                      ->where('camps.state_id=:id',['id'=>5])
                      ->andWhere('camps.status=:no',['no'=>1]);


 $command   = $query->createCommand();
 $result    = $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent with `ActiveQuery` can be like this:

```
Camp::find()
    ->select(['city_id', 'state_id', 'city_name'])
    ->distinct()
    ->joinWith('city')
    ->where([
        'state_id' => 5,
        'status' => 1,
    ])
    ->orderBy(['city_name' => SORT_ASC])
    ->all();
```

And add relation to `Camp` model:

```
public function getCity()
{
    $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['state_id' => 'state_id']);
}
```

You can find docs in [Active Record section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html):

- [Querying data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data)
- [Working with relational data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data)

Comment: its not working... Can you please tell me another way of it..?
I mean by using left join...??

I have write this query in yii2 using left join... but order by method is not working... And also i am not sure is this right or not...?? Please see this qeury... is this right...??

Camp::find()
    ->select(['camp.city_id, camp.state_id, camp.city_name'])
    ->distinct('camp.city_id')
   ->from([camp])
   ->leftJoin('cities', ['cities.state_id' => 'camp.state_id'])
   ->where(['camp.state_id' => $state_id])
   ->andWhere(['camp.status' => '1'])
    ->orderBy(['cities.city_name' => SORT_ASC]);

Comment: @arogachev is wrong with method `->with('city')`. Use `->joinWith('city')`

Comment: @SantoshGaikwad No, your query is wrong. Updated the answer with `join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new Query();
    $query->select(['camps.city_id', 'camps.state_id',   'cities.city_name'])->
        from('cities')->
        innerJoin('camps','cities.state_id = camps.state_id')->
        where(['camps.state_id' => 5,'camps.status' => '1'])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this , i hope this will help you

```
$sql = " SELECT DISTINCT camps.city_id, camps.state_id, cities.city_name 
from camps 
LEFT JOIN cities
ON cities.state_id = camps.state_id
WHERE camps.state_id = 5
AND camps.status = '1'
ORDER BY cities.city_name ASC ";

$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```